# Reading only 1GB using dd command

Tags: dd

I have a USB hard drive of 32 GB, I want to know the time it takes to copy 1 GB of data from the USB drive. I tried using `dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=/dev/null`

The output is this

```
dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=/dev/null bs=1G
 28+1 records in
 28+1 records out
 30751983616 bytes (31 GB) copied, 331.297 s, 92.8 MB/s
```

is the approach used by me is correct or am I doing it wrong. I cannot use other tool, I have to use dd command only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your command is incorrect, you tell `dd` to read by 1 GB chunks, but an unlimited number of times. To only measure the time spent to read 1 GB, you need to tell `dd` to read only one block:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=/dev/null bs=1G count=1
```

Note that buffering will make that command run faster if the device has previously be read.

Comment: Can we make block size upto 1TB?

Comment: @Bidyut That depends on your `dd` implementation, GNU `dd` accepts even `T, P, E, Z,` and `Y`.

Comment: @Bidyut but a portable script should only use the `k` suffix as this is the only one supported by POSIX.

Comment: @jilliagre I need to do it for 3 TB file system too, and I need to find the amount of time it takes to copy 1 TB of file.

Comment: Your partition size is 30 GB, it cannot hold a 1 TB file system.

Comment: I am having more than one drive, and I also want to find the transfer time for those drives too, which are having more than 3 TB space

Comment: You should define what transfer time you are looking for. With that `dd` command you are measuring sequential read time which is the maximum rate a device can provide. Reading files instead of raw devices can be significantly slower, depending on their size and whether they are fragmented or not. On the other hand, reading files might be faster than the time you measure with `dd` if these files are stored on RAID devices. You might want to ask a new question with details about what you really want to measure. Moreover, you do not take write time into account here.

Answer (score 2):

First, as @jiliagre said, you're measuring the transfer time of the whole partition (31 Gb), not 1 Gb. This is shown by the last line of your output:

> 30751983616 bytes (**31 GB**) copied, 331.297 s, 92.8 MB/s

Second, since you're writing to `/dev/null` and hence blackholing the data, it only gives you the read times for your USB drive.

The real I/O transfer time will be bound by the write speed capacity of the destination device, and most probably will be slower.

Furthermore, it depends on which data you're copying. 1 Gb of small files is copied slower than a single 1-Gb file, and takes up more space in the device due to the allocation file size.

Comment: Can we make block size upto 1TB??

Comment: I hear its best to lower the block size to match the device you are reading from and increase the count number.